# Font series of math mode in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

I use the OpenSans font and the *light* font style. For text is works, but not in math mode. 
I tried `\setbeamerfont{math text}{series=\fontseries{l}}`, but it does not change anything.

I would like to use the light font style also for math mode.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[default, scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setbeamerfont{math text}{series=\fontseries{l}}    % does not change anything
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{series=\fontseries{l}}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Some Math and Text}
        here is some text in OpenSans light \\
        but $math\,mode$ is not in light: \si{\micro\second}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are OK with changing the weight of all fonts, `\renewcommand{\mddefault}{l}` could maybe help

Comment: Are you sure that the font you are using has a light math version?

Comment: @samcarter this changed the mu to a light version, but not the other "normal" characters.

Comment: @marmot I am not sure, how do I tell? The [font overview](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) shows greek and other symbols, but be no means a complete set. However, I only need at most a few special symbols.

Comment: @derptank This is what I get with `\renewcommand{\mddefault}{l}`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnG8t.png

Comment: @samcarter yes you are correct, the light font style is used. Thanks. I had changed my MWE in the meantime (added the `mathastext`package). Not every symbol is translated though.

Comment: @derptank Not every font contains every symbol.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[default, scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Some Math and Text}
    here is some text in OpenSans light \\
    but $math\,mode$ is not in light: \si{\micro\second}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me (Win10, TexLive 2018). Everything is in normal style. If I add `setbeamerfont` and `usebeamerfont` again, it produces the same result as my MWE.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that everything is set in light weight:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[default, scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setbeamerfont{math text}{series=\fontseries{l}}    % does not change anything
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{series=\fontseries{l}}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}


\renewcommand{\mddefault}{l}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Some Math and Text}
        here is some text in OpenSans light \\
        but $math\,mode$ is not in light: \si{\micro\second}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]