# \mathsf font settings ignored in Beamer slides

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

I'd like to use a certain font (Frutiger) in text and in math.  However, in math mode I'd like to use the light series not medium.  I tried the code below (using `DeclareMathAlphabet` and `SetMathAlphabet`) but it doesn't work.  See screenshot below where the "e" and the digits "0", "1", "2", "3" are typeset in medium, not light Frutiger.  ("lim" is in a different font but that's another problem I suspect.)  One observation is that the same approach does work when I prepare an article instead of Beamer slides.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\e}{\mathsf e}

\usepackage[]{frutiger}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{T1}{pfr}{l}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{T1}{pfr}{l}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{This is a test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{\e^{3\varepsilon}-\e^\varepsilon}{\varepsilon} = \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{\e^\varepsilon (\e^{2\varepsilon}-1)}{\varepsilon}
$$

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't test right now but `beamer` does a lot of font setting at `\begin{document}`. Try putting the two lines re-declaring `\mathsf` in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument` solves the "e" but not the digits which are perhaps not in `mathsf`. I tried `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{T1}{pfr}{l}{n}` but that produces an error: `Command mathrm already defined`.

Comment: This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442894/34277) suggests using `\renewcommand{\mddefault}{l}` but it changes to light series everywhere not just in math mode.

Comment: The `professionalfonts` font theme turns off some `beamer` font trickery, and might be what you need in order to specify the exact fonts yourself. However, I do not have the package to test.

Comment: By the way, you don’t need `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```latex
\usepackage{frutiger}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{T1}{pfr}{l}{n}
                 \SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{T1}{pfr}{l}{n}
                 \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{pfr}{l}{n}
                 \DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{pfr}{l}{it}
                 \DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{OMS}{pfr}{l}{n}}
\renewcommand{\mddefault}{l}
```

Apparently the `AtBeginDocument` is necessary because Beamer will otherwise override your own settings.  Thanks to @campa for the crucial pointer.

Comment: Why trigger atbegin 5 times when you can collect all five instructions in one

Comment: Thanks, changed it.